# How to group by a property in an Angular table with a single rownspan for this property?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-table

I did not find proper title for this question.

My problem is: 
For example I have a table with two columns, column car brands and column car models.
I want table to be:

like in this picture
[image: like in this picture]

In another words brand name will show up 1 time only.

My input array is in this json format:

```
[{"brand":"Audi","model":"A1"}, 
{"brand":"Audi","model":"A2"}, 
{"brand":"Audi","model":"A3"}, 
{"brand":"BMW","model":"3 Series"}, 
{"brand":"BMW","model":"5 Series"}]
```

I can't figure out how do it in angularjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to display it using the `groupBy` filter.

```js
angular.module('app',['angular.filter'])
  .controller('MainController', function($scope) { 
    $scope.cars = [{
    "brand": "Audi",
    "model": "A1"
  }, {
    "brand": "Audi",
    "model": "A2"
  }, {
    "brand": "Audi",
    "model": "A3"
  }, {
    "brand": "BMW",
    "model": "3 Series"
  }, {
    "brand": "BMW",
    "model": "5 Series"
  }];
 });
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.4.7/angular-filter.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController"> 
  <table>
    <tbody ng-repeat="(key, value) in cars | groupBy: 'brand'">
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="{{value.length}}">{{key}}</td>
        <td>{{value[0].model}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="car in value" ng-if="!$first">
        <td>{{car.model}}</td>
      </tr>    
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I am glad that you liked my `rowspan`... code and you copied it into your answer

Comment: Thank you soooo much! I knew that there must be easy solution

Comment: I accepted answer (I did not know that I can accept answer :) ), I couldn't upvote because of my low reputation :(

Answer (score 1):

```js
angular.module('app',['angular.filter'])
  .controller('MainController', function($scope) { 
    $scope.cars = [{
    "brand": "Audi",
    "model": "A1"
  }, {
    "brand": "Audi",
    "model": "A2"
  }, {
    "brand": "Audi",
    "model": "A3"
  }, {
    "brand": "BMW",
    "model": "3 Series"
  }, {
    "brand": "BMW",
    "model": "5 Series"
  }];
 });
```

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.4.7/angular-filter.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController"> 
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Brand</th>
        <th>Model</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="(key, value) in cars | groupBy: 'brand'">
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="{{value.length}}">{{key}}</td>
        <td>{{value[0].model}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in value" ng-if="!$first">
        <td>{{item.model}}</td>
      </tr>    
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make grouping the data... Try like below.

```js
var app = angular.module('exApp',[]);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope){
var values = [{"brand":"Audi","model":"A1"}, 
{"brand":"Audi","model":"A2"}, 
{"brand":"Audi","model":"A3"}, 
{"brand":"BMW","model":"3 Series"}, 
{"brand":"BMW","model":"5 Series"}];

var datass = {};
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  var brandName = values[i].brand;
  if (!datass[brandName]) {
    datass[brandName] = [];
  }
  datass[brandName].push(values[i].model);
}
var mynewArray = [];
for (var brandName in datass) {
  mynewArray.push({brand: brandName, model: datass[brandName]});
}
$scope.newData = mynewArray;

//console.log(mynewArray);

// --or--
var group_to_values = values.reduce(function(obj,item){
    obj[item.brand] = obj[item.brand] || [];
    obj[item.brand].push(item.model);
    return obj;
}, {});

var groups = Object.keys(group_to_values).map(function(key){
    return {brand: key, model: group_to_values[key]};
});
//$scope.newData = groups;
//console.log(group_to_values);
//console.log(groups);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<style>th,td,tr{border:1px solid}</style>
<body ng-app="exApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
<table>
<tr><th>car</th><th>model</th></tr>
<tr ng-repeat="new in newData">
<td>{{new.brand}}</td>
<td>
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in new.model track by $index"><td>{{value}}</td></tr></table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```