# Angular9 GroupBy ngFor after split

Tags: angular

I am passing a JSON structure to Angular from Pandas and want to group the values displayed in a table by the "selectedGroup"

For example: but with 3 columns (Group | Column | Hits)

[image]

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43584033/how-to-group-by-a-property-in-an-angular-table-with-a-single-rownspan-for-this-p)

The issue is that the first two columns are being parsed out in the angular .html:

```
<table class="table">
<thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col" >{{selectedGroup}}</th>
        <th scope="col">{{selectedColumn}}</th>
        <th scope="col">Hits</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of mvaHits | keyvalue">
        <td>{{item.key | slice: 2:-2 | split:"', '":0}}</td> 
        <td>{{item.key | slice: 2:-2 | split:"', '":1}}</td> 
        <td>{{item.value}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Is there any way to work around GrouBy with *ngFor to produce a neater table like the image above? For the json structure below, the results would all be grouped by 100.

JSON structure:

```
{
  "result": {
    "('100', '')": 1, 
    "('100', 'AS1124 Universiteit van Amsterdam')": 2, 
    "('100', 'AS11796 Airstream Communications, LLC')": 1, 
    "('100', 'AS16276 OVH SAS')": 1, 
    "('100', 'AS209 CenturyLink Communications, LLC')": 1, 
    "('100', 'AS22394 Cellco Partnership DBA Verizon Wireless')": 1, 
    "('100', 'AS24608 Wind Tre S.p.A.')": 1, 
    "('100', 'AS3329 Vodafone-panafon Hellenic Telecommunications Company SA')": 1, 
    "('100', 'AS3352 Telefonica De Espana')": 1, 
    "('100', 'AS6128 Cablevision Systems Corp.')": 1, 
    "('100', 'AS6805 Telefonica Germany')": 1, 
    "('100', 'AS8075 Microsoft Corporation')": 1
  }
}
```

Comment: Parse your data structure into a more template friendly view model in your controller or service code. Doing too much in template here.

Comment: @bryan60 this is the format that is given from pandas.

Comment: That’s fine... write a function to map it into a template friendly view model.... nothing requires you to use the backend data model in template. It’s a good practice to write view models

Comment: @bryan60 do you happen to have/know an example somewhere that I can use as a reference? 


From what i'm understanding, you're saying to convert the data structure to another format, like so?:
{ "result": { "100": [{' ':1}, {'AS1124 Universiteit van Amsterdam':2},{'AS11796 Airstream Communications, LLC': 1}, 
...
]}}

Comment: I’d go even further. Just convert it to as close to the template as possible. An Array of objects with whatever properties are appropriate. Group, hits and column if that’s what you want? Template is not the best place to do complex transforms when you have the full power of typescript to do it